# Синхронно обработать пару запросов из redis

Tags: node.js, redis, асинхронность

Мне необходимо вытащить значения двух ключей из базы и обработать их совместно, но не могу понять, как учесть асинхронность выполнения запросов...

```
var hash1 = {}, hash2 = {};
clientRedis.hgetall("hashkey1", function(err,obj){
    hash1 = obj;
});
clientRedis.hgetall("hashkey2", function(err,obj){
    hash2 = obj;
});
// здесь делаем манипуляции с hash1 и hash2
```

Поскольку получение хэшей базы в объекты выполняется асинхронно, мне необходимо решение, которое "дождется" выполнение обоих запросов для дальнейших манипуляций  с `hash1` и `hash2`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var hash1, hash2;

clientRedis.hgetall("hashkey1", function(err,obj){
    hash1 = obj;
    success();
});

clientRedis.hgetall("hashkey2", function(err,obj){
    hash2 = obj;
    success();
});

function success() {
   if(hash1 != undefined && hash2 != undefined) {
      // you code
   }
}
```

Возможно так?

Comment: да, это работает. Но я еще видел на стековерфлоу примеры, там  якобы команды редиса в ноде можно писать цепочками, как в жквери... не сталкивались с таким?

Comment: @deivan с редисом не работал. Возможно стоит дождаться другого ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, нашел радикальное средство: [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), отменно подходит для серии асинхронных запросов.

Comment: Мне кажется что все запросы в Redis выполняются асинхронно?! Мне видеться тут два варианта решения: MULTI/EXEC и второй вариант - можно в callback первого запроса, сделать второй запрос и в callback этого второго запроса уже делать что-то с полученными данными с полной уверенностью, что в наличии есть все что нужно.